# Specflow Bindings from External Assemblies is not working and Could not load assembly file or assembly

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-assembly, specflow

I'm trying to use `ContextInjection`, by using `IObjectContainer` and Specflow.
I have multiple projects inside a solution (necessary for my project), so I think it's probably the reason. `Base`, `PageObjects` and `Steps` are laid on different projects.

Can I register webdriver instance and carry it through other projects? I tried that using specflow, but it didn't work.

It doesn't even enter the `Steps` class while debugging. While compiling, it skips all the step lines on `.feature` file and throws an exception at the end: `BoDi.ObjectContainerException: 'Interface cannot be resolved: OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver`.

When I remove the constructor it goes at least to the definition method on `Steps` class.

**EDIT:**
Actually this is not even finding the `[Bindings]`. I noticed that putting these `Hooks` on the same project, it works. So I found out that is probably all about Bindings from `Specflow External Assembly`. I tried to configure the `app.config` with the information but it didn't work.
Here's the code I put on `app.config`:

```
<specFlow>
  <stepAssemblies>
    <stepAssembly assembly="AssemblyNameOfMyProject" />
  </stepAssemblies>
</specFlow>
```

After this, I'm getting now:

```
Techtalk.Specflow error: Could not load assembly file or assembly
```

Here it goes:

`BaseTest` class:

```
    [Binding]
    public class BaseGUITest
    {
        public IWebDriver driver;

        public IObjectContainer container;

        public BaseGUITest(IObjectContainer container)
        {
            this.container = container;
        }


        [BeforeScenario(Order = 0)]
        public void BrowseInitialize()
        {

            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            container.RegisterInstanceAs<IWebDriver>(driver);

        }
```

`Page` class:

```
namespace PageObjects
{
    public class SearchPage
    {
        private readonly IWebDriver driver;


        public SearchPage(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            this.driver = driver;
        }

         public IWebElement GetTxtSearch()
        {
            return driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
        }

}
```

`Steps` class:

```
namespace Features
{
    [Binding]
    public class SearchSteps
    {
        private readonly SearchPage searchPage;

        public SearchSteps(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            searchPage= new SearchPage(driver);
        }

        [Given(@"I am on search home ")]
        {
           . . .
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with hooks bindings in specflow which are very powerful, depending on your case and the binding. In  your case the interface seems like IWebDriver

```
[BeforeFeature]
    public static void RegisterConcreteType(IObjectContainer objectContainer)
    {
        var myClass = new class();
        objectContainer.RegisterInstanceAs<Iinterface>(myClass);
    }
```

Comment: actually this is not even finding the ```[Bindings]```. I noticed that putting these ```Hooks``` on the same project, it works. 
So I found out that is all about Bindings from ```Specflow External Assembly``` .
I tried to configure the ```app.config``` with the information but it didn't work. 
I'll edit this issue with these additional info so someone might help me.

Comment: Hi @FabioCardoso, any updates on this thread? Did u manage to make it work? I'm facing the same issue, i have a Steps.proj calling a Helpers.proj where exists a method with a [BeforeScenario] hook. But it works only when both files are in the same project.

Comment: Just adding an update here, i was not able to make it work with the files in different projects, so i created a separate class with the hooks bindings and put it together with the Steps project. That did the trick for me. This post help me to follow a new path: https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/specflow-bindings-hooks-step-reuse/, and this one as well https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Bindings/Hooks.html

Comment: Yep. Thais is the only workaround so far I guess. Hopefully they will do something about this in next release versions. Those objectContainers helped me a lot to carry driver instance throughout the Test run